# Small product symbol in cases environment

Tags: symbols, align, cases

Suppose I would like to get this

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\prod
\end{align*}

\begin{align}
    \varphi (s) = T_n (s) =
    \begin{cases}
      \text{pro $n$ liché } & 2^{2m}s\prod\limits_{\mu = 1}^{m} (s^2 + \Omega_{0\mu}^2)\,,\ m = \frac{n - 1}{2} \\
      nn & nn     
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

First `\prod` symbol is there for comparison with the size of the `\prod` which is much smaller in `cases` environment below.

I would like to have same sized `\prod` symbol in `cases` like the bigger one.

Where is the problem? Is there any reason to not doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smaller `\prod` is in `\textstyle` (an inline style).  You can override it by specifying `\displaystyle` prior to `\prod`.  You will notice that the fraction `{n-1}{2}` also changes in size, again because of the difference between text style and display style math.  The `cases` environment choses to set its cases in `\textstyle`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\prod
\end{align*}

\begin{align}
    \varphi (s) = T_n (s) =
    \begin{cases}
      \text{pro $n$ liché } & 2^{2m}s\displaystyle\prod\limits_{\mu = 1}^{m} (s^2 + \Omega_{0\mu}^2)\,,\ m = \frac{n - 1}{2} \\
      nn & nn     
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

use `mathtools` instead `amsmath` and then use `dcases` instead `cases`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\prod
\end{align*}

\begin{align}
    \varphi (s) = T_n (s) =
    \begin{dcases}
      \text{pro $n$ liché } & 2^{2m}s\prod\limits_{\mu = 1}^{m} (s^2 + \Omega_{0\mu}^2)\,,\ m = \frac{n - 1}{2} \\
      nn & nn
    \end{dcases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]